# Ask About Javaswing ImageIcon

Tags: java

```
    int x = label.getSize().width;
    int y = label.getSize().height;
    int ix = image.getWidth();
    int iy = image.getHeight();
    int dx = 0;
    int dy = 0;

    if(x/y > ix/iy) {
        dy = y;
        dx = dy*ix /iy;
    } else {
        dx = x;
        dy = dx*iy /ix;
    }
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(dx, dy, image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
```

and FULL CODE:https://paste.ubuntu.com/26227642/

I just know this code is meaning make scale image is not distorted. Why is that?

Comment: Please change the title of your question something meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(x /y >ix /iy) {
    dy = y;
    dx = dy*ix /iy;
}else {
    dx = x;
    dy = dx*iy /ix;
}
```

This whole thing is done for making same `Aspect Ratio` of your `label`, as your `ImageIcon`.so that it would not distort.

The first condition in `if statement` means **Aspect ratio`x/y` of your label is more than the aspect ratio of the image`ix/iy`**.so it first set the `height` `dy` of  the label to the height of the image `y`, and for the making the same aspect ratio as the label it multiply it with the aspect ratio `ix/iy` of the image ie `ix/iy`

And same thing with your `else block`.when `aspect ratio` is more.